# Using cURL with stdin

Tags: curl, twitter

I'm trying to use the Twitter API to convert user ids to handles.

currently I have this:

```
curl --request GET --url 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?user_id=<id>' --header 'authori
zation: Bearer $BEARER_TOKEN' | jq . | grep "screen_name" | awk 'NR==1' | cut -d '"' -f4
```

Which prints out the handle perfectly.
My challenge is that I have a program outputting large amounts of ids, and I need to pipe them to curl to run on every one of them.
So, how would I replace `<id>` in the above code with stdin?